# How do I make use of the newline character from my txt file to get the lcd cursor to the next line?

Tags: c, newline, atmega, lcd

I'm writing a program to read characters from a .txt file and send this data serially to the UART of MCU ATMEGA2560. The LCD display attached to this MCU should display the characters one after another in a line. Once I encounter a newline character '\n', the next line of the .txt line should be printed in the following line of the LCD display. Now the problem that I'm facing here is although I'm able to print the characters one after the other on the LCD, the newline character does not move the cursor to the beginning of the following row. Instead a Japanese(or I'm not sure) character gets printed in its place and the characters of the next line get printed on the same line as the others. I only need assistance in getting the newline to be treated by the LCD as a command/request so that the cursor moves to the next line instead of printing a random special character on the same line.

I've serially read the characters from the txt file using pySerial. I've done the appropriate encoding and am running on Windows 10. I've also written the characters one by one on to the UART. This is a part of the code which does the serial writing with the necessary encoding. I'm not sure if this is where I'm going wrong.

```
with open(args.file) as f:
        for line in f:
            for ch in line:
                serialPort.write(ch.encode())
```

Coming to the C code, the data is received serially and characters received are stored in a variable. I've tried appending the characters but I think that seems to be causing the problem.

```
    volatile unsigned char data;
    unsigned char h[] ;

    //Function to print string on LCD
    void lcd_string(char *str)
{
    while(*str != '\0')
    {
        lcd_wr_char(*str);
        str++;
    }
}
    void append(char* s, char c)
    {
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len]=c;
        s[len+1]='\0';
    }

    SIGNAL(SIG_USART2_RECV)         // ISR for receive complete interrupt
    {
        data = UDR2;
        UDR2 = data;
        append(h,data);
    }

    //The main program which has to do the job. 

    int main(void)
    {   
        init_devices();
        lcd_set_4bit();
        lcd_init();
            while(1)
        {
            lcd_cursor(1,1);
            lcd_string(h);
        }       
    }
```

Serial data being transmitted to the UART is of this format '11, 23, 8\nC1, A5, F3 #' The hash indicates the end of serial data.

On the LCD, it should be displayed as follows:

11, 23, 8

C1, A5, F3

Any help is gladly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try carriage return? or both?

Comment: `The LCD display` what LCD display? `lcd_set_4bit` looks like HD44780. And HD44780 have specifyc commands that set cursor positions. Familiarize yourself with them. Read the documentation for HD44780 and arduino HD44780 libraries. You  probably have to handle newline character manually and set the cursor position to the next line.

Comment: Never mind. I solved the problem on my own. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @KarthikNayak then mark as solved and edit or answer this question maybe someone will have same problem.

Comment: @dunajski Yes. Updated. Guess I was too caught up with my project work. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the append function wasn't taking in the newline character as is. Here is how I solved my problem.

```
ISR(USART2_RX_vect)     // ISR for receive complete interrupt
{
    data[count]= UDR2;
    UDR2 = data[count];
    if(data[count] == 0x0A)
    {
        lcd_cursor(2,1);
        pos = count;
        count++;
        flag = FALSE;
    }
    else if(count > pos && flag == FALSE)
    {
        lcd_wr_char(data[count]);
        x[a]=data[count];
        a++;
        count++;
        flag = FALSE;
    }
    else if(flag==TRUE)
    {
        lcd_wr_char(data[count]);
        y[b]=data[count];
        b++;
        count++;
        flag = TRUE;
    }
}
```

I compared the incoming data to the newline character hex value (0x0A), and if found equal, skip that character and move the cursor to the 2nd line of the lcd display.